# ICU Formats - Force decimals

Tags: google-visualization, icu

I am using Google Visualization and am wondering how I can force two decimal digits in the axis labels.

```
vAxes:[
     {title:'Click-through-Rate', format:'#,###.####%'}, // Axis 1
     {title:'Cost-per-Click (CHF)', format:'CHF #,###.##'}, // Axis 2
],
```

The labels for axis 2 still show as CHF 0.3.

On a side note: What does ',' actually separate?

I already read through http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details however this documentation really doesn't help me at all in understanding how ICU patterns work.

All the best and thanks

Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `0` to indicate that the formatter should use placeholder 0's: eg. `'CHF #,###.00'` formats `0.3` as `'CHF 0.30'`.

The `,` tells the formatter how to handle large number groupings.  The ICU pattern recognizes two uses of the `,`: the first instance to the left of the decimal separator (`.`) is used for the smallest grouping.  If there is a second `,` to the left of the first, that is used to separate large groupings.  If only one is present, it is used for all groupings.  Examples:

```
'#,###'    formats 12345 as '12,345' and 123456789 as '123,456,789'
'#,##,###' formats 12345 as '12,345' and 123456789 as '12,34,56,789'
'#,###,##' formats 12345 as '123,45' and 123456789 as '1,234,567,89'
```

The actual separator character used depends on locale (so `'123,456,789'` might be `'123.456.789'` in some European formats).